# moving sidebar menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

hello I have a vertical menu and I want it to move with scrolling up or down
I have this javascript code

```
$(function() {

    var offset = $("#cssmenu69").offset();
    var topPadding = 5;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $("#cssmenu69").stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $("#cssmenu69").stop().animate({                
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

this code works very fine for me but the only problem is that the menu pushing the footer away when it reaches it
what should  I add to the above code to prevent that?

Comment: Where's the PHP in this?

Comment: Or the CSS for that matter?

Comment: @MCMXCII I'm assuming they included the CSS tag due to the jQuery css.